# Can't locate the item in binary search tree c++

Tags: c++, database, binary-tree

when I run it and try to enter a valid ID it says not found for any of them, I confirmed that the .dat file is being located and opened, here is the dat file below.

```
Record# AccountID   FirstName   LastName    Balance
0   6274            James           Johnson         415.56
1   2843            Marcus          Wilson          9217.23
2   2892            Maureen         Albright        51462.56
3   8837            Debra           Douglas         27.26
4   1892            Mary            Smith           918.26
5   9523            Bruce           Gold            719.32
6   3165            John            Carlson         1496.24
7   3924            Simon           Becker          386.85
8   6023            John            Edgar           9.65
9   5290            George          Truman          16110.68
10  8529            Ellen           Fairchild       86.77
11  1144            Donald          Williams        4114.26
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Account
{
    int acctID;      // Account identifier
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double balance;
};

struct IndexEntry
{
    int acctID;      // (key) Account identifier
    long recNum;     // Record number
};

struct TreeNode {
    IndexEntry data;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
};

// Function to insert a new node into the index tree
void insertNode(TreeNode*& root, IndexEntry data)
{
    IndexEntry record;
    record.acctID = data.acctID;
    record.recNum = data.recNum;
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new TreeNode;
        root->data = record;
        root->left = root->right = nullptr;
    }
    else if (data.acctID < root->data.acctID) {
        insertNode(root->left, record);
    }
    else if (data.acctID > root->data.acctID) {
        insertNode(root->right, record);
    }
}

// Function to search for a node with a given account ID in the index tree
TreeNode* searchNode(TreeNode* root, int acctID)
{
    if (root == nullptr || root->data.acctID == acctID) {
        return root;
    }
    else if (acctID < root->data.acctID) {
        return searchNode(root->left, acctID);
    }
    else {
        return searchNode(root->right, acctID);
    }
}

// Function to retrieve an account record from the database file
void getAccountRecord(ifstream& file, long recNum)
{
    file.seekg(recNum * sizeof(Account));
    Account record;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&record), sizeof(record));
    cout << record.acctID << "\t" << record.firstName << "\t" << record.lastName << "\t" << record.balance << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Open the database file for reading
    ifstream file("accounts.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Error opening database file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Build the index tree by reading through the database file
    TreeNode* indexTree = nullptr;
    IndexEntry record;
    long recNum = 0;
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&record), sizeof(record))) {
        record.recNum = recNum;
        insertNode(indexTree, record);
        recNum++;
    }

    // Search for account records based on account ID
    int acctID;
    cout << "Enter account ID to retrieve record: ";
    cin >> acctID;
    TreeNode* node = searchNode(indexTree, acctID);
    if (node == nullptr) {
        cout << "Account record not found!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        getAccountRecord(file, node->data.recNum);
    }

    // Clean up
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

i'm not sure if it is the binary tree that isn't being made right

Comment: `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&record), sizeof(record));` -- This cannot work.  The `Account` class contains `std::string` members, and you cannot read or write data this way.  Where did you get this assignment from, where you are trying to read/write data in this fashion?

Comment: The IO method you are using only works when you have **fixed length records** of **plain data**. Neither of these things are true in your case. You have a `std::string` in your data and your file is a text file with a header and variable length lines.

Comment: [Short and to the point](https://godbolt.org/z/eh3K3sao8).  The answer of "NO" basically shuts down the code you have now.  Now [compare to this](https://godbolt.org/z/7Gj88K8PY).

Comment: What you should to is read your input file one line at a time (remembering to discard the first line) and convert each line into the appropriate account data.

Comment: IMHO, you should place all your records into a `std::vector`.  You should then create `std::map<key, vector-index>` for each key you want to search by.  This is known as using *index tables* in database parlance.

Comment: The other piece of advice is that before you even think about a binary tree (the code for that looks OK to me BTW) you should get your file reading code written and tested. There is no point in trying to build a binary tree when you cannot read the data correctly. So put the binary tree code to one side for a minute, and just write a program that reads the input file and prints the information back out. Once you have that code working then you can reintroduce the binary tree code. This is how you should always program, solve each piece of the problem separately.

Comment: read the file using `>>` to extract each column